# You cannot switch to an Apps Script-created Cloud Platform project - associate an Apps Script file with Cloud Project

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to attach a new app script to my Google Cloud project. From the Apps Script code editor, I'm trying to connect to to Cloud Platform project using the Menu:

Resources > Cloud Platform project

but when I add the project number I get the error message

> 'You cannot switch to an Apps Script-created Cloud Platform project.'

I'm trying to avoid having to create a new Cloud Project, any ideas?

[image: Cannot switch]

Comment: You cannot switch to an Apps Script managed GCP project anymore. Not since Google made substantial changes to their platform over the last few years (primarily in 2018 and 2019).

Comment: As far as I know, you won't be able to avoid creating a new Cloud Project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error message states, you can't add a new Apps Script to a Cloud Console Project which was created by Apps Script.  These Apps-Script created cloud console projects are managed automatically and for whatever reason have this limitation.

Create a new Cloud Console Project manually, then associate your existing apps script project with the manually created cloud console project via the Resources menu in the script editor.

Comment: This wording needs fixing. Simply create a new Cloud Console Project manually, then associate your existing apps script project with the manually created cloud console project via the Resources menu in the script editor.  No need to create a new *apps script* project.

Comment: I edited your answer.  If it's wrong, please edit or comment back.