# No Option to Switch Apps Script Project to a new Cloud Platform Project?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to add existing apps script projects to a standard Cloud Platform Project so that I have more control over the errors and logging.  I have no trouble migrating recently created apps script projects to my new Cloud Platform Project, but I can't get older apps script projects to do it.

New apps script projects have it right in the resources menu:
[image: new apps script project]

But the older apps script projects completely lack the "Cloud Platform project..." option under resources:[image]

I can't seem to find any documentation on why this is the case, or on how to add older scripts.  Can anyone help me here?

Thanks!

Comment: https://tanaikech.github.io/2019/07/05/linking-cloud-platform-project-to-google-apps-script-project/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59845949/you-cannot-switch-to-an-apps-script-created-cloud-platform-project-associate-a

Answer (score 1):

### If you cannot see the menu `Ressources > Cloud Platform project` most likely you are not the owner of the script

Either this is the reason, or something else  -your best bet is to go on `File > Make a copy` to create a new Apps Script file.